# Nuxt 3 runtimeConfig returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxt3

I am using runtimeConfig on a page but it is undefined

In `nuxt.config.ts`

```
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
      local: {
        client_id: 'id goes here',
        client_secret: 'ueyqwriwyriry'
      }
    }
  }
```

In my page `index.vue`

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

console.log(config.public.local.client_id); // undefined
console.log(config.public.apiUrl) //undefined
```

When I use the nuxt docs basic example, it works, but if I add an extra variable, both are undefined.

```
runtimeConfig: {
  // Private keys are only available on the server
  apiSecret: '123',
  // Public keys that are exposed to the client
  public: {
    apiBase: '/api'
  }
}

in index.vue => console.log(config.public.apiBase) // works
```

```
runtimeConfig: {
  // Private keys are only available on the server
  apiSecret: '123',
  // Public keys that are exposed to the client
  public: {
    apiBase: '/api',
    anotherKey: 'test',
  }
}

in index.vue => console.log(config.public.apiBase) // undefined 
console.log(config.public.anotherKey) // undefined
```

Comment: I don't see any mistakes on your code. I also tried it on stackblitz and I am able to see the public data inside the `config`. Try restarting your server
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-h79fy2?file=nuxt.config.ts

Comment: I also have no idea what might be wrong. Is there any way that my app setup is the issue? Unfortunately, I can't show it here but it is a normal nuxt3 app with the default directory structure